# Routing KVM VM traffic over wireguard from host OS

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, kvm-virtualization, wireguard

I'm trying to setup a Wireguard tunnel on my host OS and route all network traffic from a specific KVM VM over this Wireguard VPN. My KVM VMs are setup using bridged networking. The interface name on the host OS of the specific VM that I want to route through the VPN is 'viifv1424'. These are the commands I've run to try and achieve this, but it seems the VM is just routing as normal still, and not routing through the VPN:

These are the exact commands I ran. The VM interface name is viifv1424, and the wireguard interface is named wg_viifv1424

```
#Setup fireguard tunnel
ip link add dev wg_viifv1424 type wireguard
wg setconf wg_viifv1424 /etc/wireguard/wg_viifv1424.conf

#routing table
ip link set dev wg_viifv1424 up
ip route add default dev wg_viifv1424 table 100
ip rule add iif viifv1424 table 100

#iptables rules
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg_viifv1424 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i viifv1424 -o wg_viifv1424 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i viifv1424 -o wg_viifv1424 -j ACCEPT
```

wg_viifv1424.conf contents:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = XXXXXXX
[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXXXX
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint = 1.2.3.4:51820
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

At the point your host is making the relevant routing decision, the input interface (`iif` in your rule) is the bridge device, not `viifv1424`.

### Example setup

On my system, I'm running a typical libvirt setup. I have a network `default` associated with bridge device `virbr0`. If I create a virtual machine on that network, the virtual machine gets attached to virtual interface `vnet0`.

I have a wireguard interface configured as `wg0`, with address `192.168.64.14`.

### Rules that don't work

If I set up the equivalent to your rules:

```
ip route add default dev wg0 table 100
ip rule add prio 100 iif vnet0 table 100
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And then attempt to `ping 8.8.8.8`, I see the echo request go out the host default interface.

### Rules that do work

If instead I set up the policy rule with the bridge interface as the input interface:

```
ip route add default dev wg0 table 100
ip rule add prio 100 iif virbr0 table 100
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then I see the request go out `wg0` as desired. Running `tcpdump -i wg0 -n` I see:

```
19:05:19.217001 IP 192.168.64.14 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 26, seq 1, length 64
19:05:19.274453 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.64.14: ICMP echo reply, id 26, seq 1, length 64
```

Comment: This makes sense, but, you don't specify 'venet0' anywhere in your rules. I have multiple VMs on this host, all using the same bridge device. I only one specific VMs to route over the Wireguard tunnel. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You could route by source ip address instead of by input interface. You could attach your virtual machine to a different bridge interface. You could set up wireguard *inside* your virtual machine. You might be able to use an iptables rule to set a packet mark on traffic coming in the virtual interface and use *that* in your policy rule instead.

Comment: Why doesn’t it work when I try to route by the VM virtual interface though? This would be ideal for the setup I want. A VM can have multiple IPs, so I’d rather not use source IP, and I don’t want it on the guest.

Comment: Because from a networking perspective the bridge device is where packets enter the host; the tap device associated with the vm is like the remote end of an ethernet cable.